# Show formula of inverse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let

p(Y)=(-Y)^n + a_(n-1)*Y^(n-1) + ... + a_0

be the characteristic polynomial of matrix A.
Show that A is invertible, if and only if a_0 isn't zero and that inverse of A is

A^(-1)=q(A),

where q is polynomial.

---

So i'm having trouble showing that inverse is polynomial of A.

For the first part i went this way; A is invertible when its determinant isnt zero. 
p(Y)=det(A-YI), so p(0)=det(A), so det(A)=a_0.

For inverse i dont even know how to start.
Any guidance is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Multiply [Cayley-Hamilton relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem) $$ A^n + a_{n-1} A^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1 A + a_0 = 0$$ by $A^{-1}.$

Comment: Oh, thats so simple, thank you very much!

Comment: @leia you are welcome. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

some more hints can be found in Cayley-Hamilton theorem, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem